# lua5.2 call c dll in windows

Tags: c, windows, dll, lua, lua-api

My C code is below:

#### skypeAnalyzer.h

```
#include "lua.h" 
#include "lualib.h" 
#include "lauxlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

//dll export func
int _declspec(dllexport) luaopen_skypeAnalyzer(lua_State* L);
```

#### skypeAnalyzer.c

```
#include "skypeAnalyzer.h"
#include <windows.h> 
#include <wincrypt.h> 

int run(lua_State* L){
    printf("------->>> Hi! %s \n", lua_tostring(L, 1));
    return 0;
}


struct luaL_Reg IrLibs[] = {

    { "run", run },
    { NULL, NULL }
};


int luaopen_skypeAnalyzer(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newlib(L, IrLibs);
    return 1;
}
```

And lua code is below:

```
require "skypeAnalyzer"
skypeAnalyzer.run("Lua")
```

I compile dll in vs express 2013 and generate skypeAnalyzer.dll, but when I run lua code, there are the following error:

```
C:\Lua>lua52.exe skypeAnalyzer.lua
lua52.exe: C stack overflow
stack traceback:
        [C]: in ?
        [C]: in function 'require'
        C:\Lua\skypeAnalyzer.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
```

How to dynamically call lua52.dll when compile the dll?  How to set in VS 2013?  I compile dll in vs express 2013 and generate skypeAnalyzer.dll, but when I run lua code, there are the following error:

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

Your lua code is requiring itself.

Use a different name for the `.dll` and `.lua` files.

With lua 5.1 you would have gotten the slightly more useful error trace:

```
lua5.1: ./foo.lua:1: loop or previous error loading module 'foo'
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        ./foo.lua:1: in main chunk
        [C]: ?
        [C]: ?
```